# draw with QPaint on loaded QPixmap does not work

Tags: qt, qpainter, qpixmap

I can draw a Line on my Qlabel by doing this:

```
    QPixmap *myPixmap;
    myPixmap = new QPixmap();
    myPixmap->fill(Qt::red);
    QPainter painter(myPixmap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    painter.drawLine(1, 1, 50, 50);
    ui.label->setPixmap(*myPixmap);
```

That works. I get a red label with a blue line.

But now i want do draw that line over a 1.jpg like this:

```
    QPixmap *myPixmap;
    myPixmap = new QPixmap(ui.label->size());
    myPixmap->load("c:\\temp\\1.jpg");
    QPainter painter(myPixmap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    painter.drawLine(1, 1, 50, 50);
    ui.label->setPixmap(*myPixmap);
```

Unfortunately now i only get my 1.jpg but no blue line over it.

Can anybody explain this?
I work on Win10 / QT5.6.1

---

Edit to clarify my mistake.

Thanks to the comments of @musicamante and @A.R.M i figured out that the blue line was there but just out of sight because it was to large for the Mainwindow. Unfortunately my original 1.jpg was unicolored so i did not notice that.

I added a frame to my 1.jpg so i can now show the problem i had with 2 screenshots:

with line
[image]
without line
[image]

Comment: Is that the exact code you use? Because at least the first doesn't seem valid (you cannot draw on a null pixmap). And why are you using such an **old** version of Qt?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code i use. The myPixmap ist defined elsewhere. I have edited my post. There was no reason to upgrade my Qt version yet.

Comment: The point is not where `myPixmap` is defined, but the fact that you create a *null pixmap* (`QPixmap()`) which has no size defined, which has two side effects: 1. the painter should not be able to paint; 2. the pixmap cannot be set on the label because it's null (no size). Even considering that you're using such an old version of Qt shouldn't matter, since the behavior would've been able in Qt4 too, which leads me to think that you're doing other things somewhere else. Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Using the second snippet, I made this [mre]: https://hastebin.com/share/piqaxayuca.cpp. However, I could not get the same results as you (Qt 6 and Qt 5.15, Fedora KDE), I get the desired outcome, which is the image drawn with a blue line on top of it.